# VS2010 C# 64bit app throws OutOfMemoryException after consuming 1.5GB of memory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, out-of-memory

I want to see the System.OutOfMemoryException and the memory consumed in the task manager, when the app is built against x64. There are two drop-downs in the Build tab in the app properties: "Platform target" and "Platform", both are set to x64.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<long> lst = new List<long>();
            while (true)
            {
                lst.Add(long.MaxValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is indeed showing OutOfMemoryException...but when it stops, the task manager is showing a number like 1587443K which is 1.5GB which would I expect if it was built against x86.
Yes, the operating system is 64bit.

Am I forgetting something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I forgetting something else?

Yes - in .NET 4, there was still a 2GB-per-object limit. (You could use much more memory, but not in a single object.) I suspect your list needs to reallocate its internal buffer, requiring ~3GB in a single array.

You may be pleased to hear that [.NET 4.5 supports larger objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx) if you set the [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) configuration parameter.